# Clicked code highlighting not working on MonoDevelop 4.0.1 and higher (shipped with Unity 4.3)

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I just came from Visual Studio but I'm pretty sure we had this in MonoDevelop that was shipped with older versions of Unity.

I want to click on a variable/class/method/etc. and have it - and all of its usage in the file (syntax aware) - highlighted.

I'm using the newer version of MonoDevelop 4.0.1 that is being shipped with Unity 4.3.

I have enabled *Syntax Highlighting* in the preferences, but nothing. Is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences > Text Editor > Markers And Rulers

Then Check the check box "Highlight identifier reference".

That should do the work.